# CA2000:Dispose objects before loosing scope

Tags: .net, dynamics-crm, code-analysis

I m havin following code in one method,while doing code analysis 
it is giving me following message for this secton of code

> CA2000    Dispose objects before losing scope In method
>   'AddressHistory.UpdateFlagInApplicationEntity(bool)', call
>   System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new OrganizationService("Xrm")'
>   before all references to it are out of
>   scope.    MasterPortal    AddressHistory.aspx.cs  269

I have used using to solved this,
but it is still showing this message for 'new OrganizationService,is it because of in using section I wrote new key word two time ,do I need it to declare separately??

plz help me out

```
if (applicationDetails.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    Guid applicationId = applicationDetails.Entities[0].Id;
    if (applicationId != null)
    {
        using (var updateContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(new OrganizationService("Xrm")))
        {
            var applicationToupdate = new Entity(ApplicationsEntity.ENTITYNAME) { Id = applicationId };
            applicationToupdate[ApplicationsEntity.SIA_SECTIONCOMPLETEDADDRESSES] = flagValue;
            updateContext.Attach(applicationToupdate);
            updateContext.UpdateObject(applicationToupdate);
            updateContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you've already used `using` with the `OrganizationService` instance. Just remember to pass that instance to the `OrganizationServiceContext` constructor, like this:

```
if (applicationDetails.Entities.Count > 0)
{
    Guid applicationId = applicationDetails.Entities[0].Id;
    if (applicationId != null)
    {
        using (var service = new OrganizationService("Xrm"))
        using (var updateContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service))
        {
            var applicationToupdate = new Entity(ApplicationsEntity.ENTITYNAME) { Id = applicationId };
            applicationToupdate[ApplicationsEntity.SIA_SECTIONCOMPLETEDADDRESSES] = flagValue;
            updateContext.Attach(applicationToupdate);
            updateContext.UpdateObject(applicationToupdate);
            updateContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```